# Apache Solr - how to return all (matching and non-matching) results in sequence from a multiple condition query?

Tags: python, solr

General question:

For the Apache Solr API, is there a useful parameterization or configuration method to retrieve all matching and non-matching results in sequence from a multiple condition query?

Mock example query using dog breeds:

`https://example.solr.api/?q=breed:(poodle bulldog collie)&rows=10&wt=json`

or long hand

`https://example.solr.api/?q=breed:poodle OR breed:bulldog OR breed:collie&rows=10&wt=json`

Say that two of the three dog breeds are present but the bulldog record is not present. Typically, the search would return two records. Is there a way to return all of the results in order with a null or default value for non-matching conditions,

e.g., `[{ poodle record }, None, { collie record }]`?

Keeping the same sequence as applied in logical OR conditions is useful for processing batch requests, especially for fuzzy requests where a 1-1 correspondence is not always immediately obvious.

Thank you in advance for your time!

I'm uncertain of the solution.

Comment: Given that there is no certainty that every part of your query would return a single document (i.e. how many None/null values there should be between two hits), I can't really think of any decent way to do this. You'd probably have to run the queries one by one, or you can use the debug information (include `debug=all`) to look at which terms matched a given document.